# ASP.NET Membership getuserbyID

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

How I can get User by ID?
MembershipUser mu=Membership.GetUser("UserName");
But, I want get user by ID, but not by name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(id);
```

This will work (expects object ProviderUserKey) - which is GUID by the default asp.net membership provider.

Answer (score 1):

Since user names  are unique, you can query your application database `Users` table to get the `UserName` for a specific `UserID` and pass the result to `Membership.GetUser("UserName");`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using inbuilt MembershipProvider, then you'll have to write a helper method which will do the job for you and return a MembershipUser instance based on the Id to query.

If you're using your own custom MembershipProvider, in that case you can create a method overload for Membership.GetUser() which will take an Id and return a MembershipUser instance, However, you will need to cast the MembershipProvider default instance to the type of your custom MemberdhipProvider to gain the type-safe access

Answer (score 1):

If you are using(or inheriting from) the standard [SqlMemberShipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) you can use `MembershipProvider.GetUser(providerUserKey, userIsOnline)`.

Where `providerUserKey` is the GUID and `userIsOnline` is a boolean that indicates whether   the last-activity date/time stamp for the specified user should be updated or not.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152128.aspx